# Error in maven package/test commands due to external package

Tags: java, maven

In eclipse I created a maven project, and then added the reference of another java-library-project (not created through maven).

When I am trying to run commands mvn test and/or mvn package; there are error occurred as the java-library (non-maven) project's package is not found as following:

**[ERROR] D:\testmaven\src\main\java\com\ezx\testmaven\testapp.java:[9,2] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class TestJavaAapp
[ERROR] location: class testapp**

I am not really what I have to do to fix this issue, do I need to create local-repository for java-library-project(non-maven project) to package through maven? Also note this java-library-project(non-maven project) jar file is already deployed at server, so allI want to create a new maven-project jar file to deploy at server. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile/test your project with maven, you need to specify the dependencies to other libraries in the POM file. It is not enough to add a reference in the eclipse build path.

If you have a local library that is not in the maven repository, you can add this library to your local repository with the following mvn command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-your-jarfile> -DgroupId=<your-groupid> -DartifactId=<your-artifactid> -Dversion=<your-version> -Dpackaging=jar
```

After this you can add the dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>your-groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifactid</artifactId>
    <version>your-version</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now you should be able to compile and test your project with maven.

Hope that helps.